# How do I solve the Issues with express typescript RequestHandler conversion

Tags: typescript, express

I have this middleware

```
import type {NextFunction, Request, Response} from 'express';

import {getUserId} from '../utils/verifyJwt.js';

interface IValidateIDHandler extends Request {
    params: {
        userId: string;
    };
}

export const validateId = async (
    req: IValidateIDHandler,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
        const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1] || '';
        const userId = await getUserId(token);
        if(userId !== req.params.userId) {
            res.status(401).json({message: 'Unauthorized. Invalid user id.'});
            return;
        }
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({message: 'Unauthorized. Invalid token'});
    }
};
```

and in my router I'm getting the following issue in this part of the code:

```
router.put(
    '/user/:id/update-email',
    verifyTokenMiddleware as RequestHandler,
    validateId as RequestHandler,  //error is here
    updatePassword as RequestHandler
);
```

error is:

> Conversion of type '(req: IValidateIDHandler, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise' to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
> Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
> Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is not comparable to type 'IValidateIDHandler'.
> Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
> Property 'userId' is missing in type 'ParamsDictionary' but required in type '{ userId: string; }'.ts(2352)

I've previously tried to simply use the following type for Request
`req: Request<{userId: string}, unknown, {userId: string}>`

but the result is the same.